# Why can't I set up October CMS on my hosted server?

Tags: mysql, database, content-management-system, installation

I have server space with Hostmonster and would like to try [October CMS](http://octobercms.com). I've made a MYSQL database and user, added the files to a subfolder via FTP, checked permissions, run the installer with all ticks for the pre-flight check.. I fill out the form and get:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxxxx_xxxxx'@'xxxxxxxx.hostmonster.com' (using password: YES)
>
> There is a problem with the specified Database configuration.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this one. I think it was down to permissions and the hostname.. both of which needed a change.